# Login/Register for checkout page?

Tags: php, authentication, redirect

Assume user adding some products (via Add button), and then click on the checkout button.

If user have not logged in, it will redirect to a **/login** page.

After logged, how to redirect back to the checkout page?

by default, when user have logged in -  it will redirect to a **/account** page.

I have created my own login authentication class.

checkout page, sample code:

```
if ($this->memberID) {
  //show checkout page
} else {
   header("location: /login");
}
```

Note: I use jquery ajax (to php) to check login detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add before

```
header("location: /login");
```

some data to the session like:

```
$_SESSION['redirectAfterLogin'] = '/account';
```

And in Login controller after successed login, check if `$_SESSION['redirectAfterLogin']` is not empty and then just redirect to the specified url (also remember to erase that value after you use it).

Comment: I think you meant $_SESSION['redirectAfterLogin'] = '/checkout'; ?

Comment: @user622378 - Every page linking to login.php can set whatever it wants. And don't forget to call `exit()` after `header()`.